# python: error setting whisker bounds in boxplot

Tags: python, numpy, boxplot

I'm getting a perplexing error when I attempt to adjust the whisker length in boxplot -- I'd like to have the whiskers extend from the 5th to 95th percentile values, using the kwarg `whis = [5,95]`. When I do so I get the following error (copying the entire traceback):

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "boxplot_snoho_bc.py", line 125, in <module>
>      main()
>    File "boxplot_snoho_bc.py", line 64, in main
>      bp = boxplot(data[0], positions = [1], widths = 0.6, whis = [5,95])   
>    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2143, in boxplot
>      ret = ax.boxplot(x, notch, sym, vert, whis, positions, widths, patch_artist, bootstrap)
>    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 5545, in
> boxplot
>      wisk_hi = np.compress( d <= hi_val , d )
>  ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10) (42)
```

My understanding from other threads and the help docs is that this is the correct syntax, but I am new to python and am probably getting something wrong...

For the sake of clarity, here is the command causing the error:

> bp = boxplot(data[0], positions = [1], widths = 0.6, whis = [5,95])

`data` is a 8x10 numpy array; I'm plotting just one box at a time. Here's what the array looks like:

> print data
>
> [[   40.66    33.53    30.56    30.83    11.8     60.91  11.91    10.74 23.97    11.  ]
>
> [   16.19    85.69   206.25    27.16    29.22    41.69    16.44    10.41    477.75    23.95]
>
> [ 1651.     192.      16.02    29.91    14.95   123.38    31.22    11.08     29.5     16.03]
>
> [  132.5    874.5     12.51    41.5     68.25    60.22    36.91    12.27   58.84    28.33]
>
> [  145.5     26.95    25.2     33.88    44.78    40.16    16.78    18.95  36.03    16.05]
>
> [   18.89    82.94    83.56   344.     118.94    49.62    23.23    25.89  2072.      90.56]
>
> [  221.38    22.69    35.28    25.08    25.16    41.84    16.77    14.16   12.77    15.27]
>
> [   32.03  1634.      34.59   140.12    61.22    32.53    24.55    20.06   30.97    27.14]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Embarrassingly, this was a version issue with matplotlib (need at least version 1.4.0).